# match pattern in keytool command in bash script

Tags: java, bash, ssl, keytool

How to fetch certificate start with "_abc" using keytool in linux(bash shell).Trying below-

```
keytool -list -keystore /etc/pki/java/cacerts -alias _abc* -storepass "changeit"
```

but getting error -- java.lang.Exception: Alias <_abc*> does not exist.
if provide full nae "_abcdef" this will work. what would be the solution.

Comment: keytool doesn't have an option (atleast in documentation) that it supports regex or wildcard in alias. ref: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/keytool.html#keytool_option_list

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
keytool -list -keystore /etc/pki/java/cacerts -storepass "changeit" | grep _abc -A1
```

The `-A1` means "show the search hit and the next line"

Comment: I don't think that it's the correct solution. I think at first it must be made aware that keytool doesn't support pattern matching in alias (atleast nothing in documentation). Also this can is going to be system specific as there is no grep on linux and this will only get lines and will need change in case of -v

Comment: Getting this --
bash-4.2# keytool -list -keystore /etc/pki/java/cacerts -alias -storepass "changeit" | grep _abc -A2
Illegal option:  changeit
keytool -list [OPTION]...
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::


 -

Comment: OK, how we can fetch all the cert having alias srated with "_abc" and export to a file say "export.pem"

Comment: I made a mistake. `-alias` is now gone

Comment: You only need `-A1`, and if it matters to match only beginning of alias, use `grep ^_abc -A1`. bash doesn't treat `^` as special but some other shells do, so quote the regexp if you want portability.